Что использовать: запятую или двоеточие?
"Это может произойти в любой момент жизни ( , или : ) как при развитии в утробе матери, так и после рождения".

В этом предложении правильно использовать двоеточие, так как вторая часть раскрывает или поясняет первую.
Это может произойти в любой момент жизни: как при развитии в утробе матери, так и после рождения.
Двоеточие здесь вводит пояснение, когда именно это может произойти.
